# Passing on a variable from the main of a gui to a private class in java

Tags: java, class, user-interface

So I have a relatively good understanding of java, but I cannot continue on with a program I am working on until I can figure out how to pass on a variable from my main in a gui to a private class in a gui that has action listener implemented.  This was just a test I was doing to see if I could get something basic to work.

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
    Scanner inputChamps = new Scanner (new FileReader("Dazzle_Squad_Champs.txt"));

    int number = inputChamps.nextInt(); // trying to pass this on from here

    LoadButtonHandler(number);

    Dazzle_Squad myAreaObject = new Dazzle_Squad();
}

public static void LoadButtonHandler (int number) implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae) {
        System.out.println(number); // and outputting it here.. Everything else works so far
    }
}
```

Comment: The above doesn't compile. It looks like you're confusing classes and methods. A class doesn't take any argument, and doesn't return anything. Its constructor can take an argument, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

void? u are creating a method there...

```
public class LoadButtonHandler implements ActionListener 
{
    private int number;

    public LoadButtonHandler(int number){
      this.number=number;
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)  

    {
        System.out.println(number); // and outputting it here.. Everything else works so far
    }
}
```

u are mixing console application with gui :O
That listener  have to be added to a component like this

```
myAreaObject.addActionListener(new LoadButtonHandler(inputConsole));
```